# Deprecated error when creating PyTorch Deep Learning VM from the Google Cloud Marketplace

Tags: pytorch

I followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/pytorch_start_instance) to create a GCP Deep Learning VM with pytorch, but get the following error:

```
tensorflow has resource level warnings
ferracane-pytorch-chiefcomplaint-vm: The resource 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1-4-cu101-20200615' is deprecated. A suggested replacement is 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/pytorch-1-4-cu101-v20200701'.
```